# i want horizontal Scroll in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i want to make horizontal scroll in bootstrap 4 in my below code but i unable to do it

```
<div class="scroll-horz">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"> Test </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> Test </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> Test </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> Test </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> Test </div>     
  </div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"> Test </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> Test </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> Test </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> Test </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> Test </div>     
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try as shown below,

**HTML:**

```
<div class="scroll-horz">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"> Test </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> Test </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> Test </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> Test </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> Test </div>     
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"> Test </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> Test </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> Test </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> Test </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> Test </div>     
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.scroll-horz > .row {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.scroll-horz > .row > .col-md-4 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
```

Comment: @RevTech Off-course it will not work as you expected in jsfiddle because you haven't referred bootstrap.

Comment: @ChandanYS add a code snippet here (not in jsfiddle) to show your example.

Comment: i added bootstrap https://jsfiddle.net/9dzaufbc/
but the problem is i want all columns in one line

Comment: @RevTech but you getting scrollbar in JSFiddle rite?

Comment: yes but add horizontal scroll i want row columns in one line

Comment: @RevTech replace the class name col-md-4 with some other name and do the same in css too. I just tried and it worked perfectly. Because as col-md-4 is bootstrap class, it will allow only 3 columns in a row.